# How to attach c and c++ modules?

Tags: c++, c

I have two moudles:

Module1: A C program, constructs two graphs.

Module2: A C++ program, checks equivalence of the two graphs produced by module1.

I want to feed output of module1 to module2.

Module2 uses structs only and are identical to ones used in module1, only difference is that module2 contains some function overloading etc.

One way to transfer the graphs is to write them to a file and re-read and parse in module2.

**My Question is:**

Is there a method available by which I can carry the instances of structs constructed in Module1 to Module2 directly, without going through this file read/write.

Abstract example of what I want to say:

```
// Module1: 

struct s1 {
   int a;
};

void main (){
    struct s1 s;
    s.a = 10;
}

// Module2:
struct s1{
    int a;  // Note the same structure and variable name.
};

void print (struct s1 s){
    cout << s.a;
}

void main (){
    struct s1 s;
     print (s);
}
```

Question repharsed:
Is there a technique available by which I can feed the structure created in Module1 directly (via main memory only) to Module2; **without writing to file first and then re-reading**?

Comment: Search how to use shared memory in whatever platform you're using.

Comment: By the way, the `main` function, in both C and C++ languages, returns an `int` to the operating system.  Always.

Comment: In the olden days, people used files to share data between programs.  You may need to create another file to act as a semaphore.

Comment: If you have the sources and are building a single application, just call a function.

Comment: There is no reason you can't link `C` and `C++` object files together to make a single program.

Comment: In addition to the answers below - if you have the source code of both modules, why not compiling them both with C++ compiler and eliminating the problem? In the vast majority of cases C code is portable to C++ either transparently or with very little effort.

Comment: Answer by Galik solves it.
Using shared memory has its own problems. I required interprocess communication.
Modifying code is not an option because one of the modules is written by someone else. Anyway answer by Galik solves it with minimum modifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason the two modules can't be linked together into a single program. The main thing to remember is that the `C` function declarations (in the `C` header file **module1.h**) need to be marked as having `C` language linkage to the `C++` compiler.

You can do that using `__cplusplus` guards:

**module1.h**

```
#ifndef MODULE_1_H
#define MODULE_1_H

// tell the C++ compiler this header is for 
// a module written in C
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct
{
    int i;
    double d;
} Graph;

Graph construct_a_graph();

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif // MODULE_1_H
```

**module1.c**

```
#include "module1.h"

Graph construct_a_graph()
{
    Graph g;
    g.i = 2;
    g.d = 7.9;

    return g;
}
```

**module2.h**

```
#ifndef MODULE_2_H
#define MODULE_2_H

#include "module1.h"

void process_graph(Graph g);

#endif // MODULE_2_H
```

**module2.cpp**

```
#include "module2.h"

void process_graph(Graph g)
{
    // do stuff in C++
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"

int main()
{
    Graph g = construct_a_graph(); // C function

    process_graph(g); // C++ function
}
```

**Compiling with GCC:**

```
gcc -c -o module1.o module1.c // C module
g++ -c -o module2.o module2.cpp // C++ module
g++ -o main main.cpp module1.o module2.o // link fine
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to make a library (.dll/.so/..) out of both, that contains the implementation of the class and provides a C- and a C++-interface for accessing it.

You can then either store the instances of your objects in the library and pass handles/copies to the user (depending on what you need) or use the shared memory and pass pointers between your modules.
Under VisualStudio the shared-memory-option is called "Multithreaded-DLL (\Md)", i don't know the exact option for other OS/Compilers.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Galik, both modules can be linked to a single program. As an alternative, the message passing interface [(MPI)](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/) can be used to communicate pieces of information from a program to another. Here is how it could be done in your case.

- CPP program `module2` spawns a process calling `module1`.
- `module1` sets the value of the member of a struct s1 `s` and sends the structure as a buffer to `module2`.
- `module2` receives a copy of the buffer, puts it into a struct s1 and prints the value of the member.

Here is the c++ code of program `module2`, to be compiled by `mpiCC module2.cpp -o module2`:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct s1{
    int a;  // Note the same structure and variable name.
};

void print (struct s1 s){
    cout << s.a;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  errcode;
    MPI_Comm intercomm,intracomm;
    MPI_Info info;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    char command[15];
    sprintf(command,"%s","./module1");


    int ierr=MPI_Comm_spawn(command,MPI_ARGV_NULL,1,MPI_INFO_NULL,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&intercomm,&errcode);
    if (ierr != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("spaw failed\n");
    }
    // intercomm has two group. One with the parent, one with the children
    MPI_Intercomm_merge(intercomm,0,&intracomm);
    int size, rank;  
    MPI_Comm_size(intracomm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(intracomm, &rank);
    cout<<"parent has rank "<<rank<<" in communicator of size "<<size<<endl;

    struct s1 s;
    MPI_Recv(&s,sizeof(struct s1),MPI_CHAR,1,0,intracomm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&intracomm); //disconnect after all communications
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&intercomm);

    print (s);
    cout<<endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the c code of program `module1`, to be compiled by `mpicc module1.c -o module1`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s1 {
    int a;
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int rank,size;
    MPI_Comm parentcomm,intracomm;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );

    //MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_get_parent( &parentcomm );
    if (parentcomm == MPI_COMM_NULL){fprintf(stderr,"module1 : i'm supposed to be the spawned process!");exit(1);}

    MPI_Intercomm_merge(parentcomm,1,&intracomm);

    MPI_Comm_size(intracomm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(intracomm, &rank);
    printf("child had rank %d in communicator of size %d\n",rank,size);

    struct s1 s;
    s.a = 10;
    MPI_Send(&s,sizeof(struct s1),MPI_CHAR,0,0,intracomm);
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&intracomm); //disconnect after all communications
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&parentcomm);
    MPI_Finalize();  
    return 0;
}
```

The whole thing is ran by `mpirun -np 1 module2`.